# In Kendo Ui how to reflect the changes occurred in grid view on to the chart ?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile, kendo-treeview, kendo-dataviz

I have a grid view, when i change some nodes or label or parameter it should be reflected in chart. How to make this possible in Kendo UI using mvvm ?

Comment: You'll be able to get more answers if you provided a little more information. What resources have you consulted? Can you give us some example code to see your current approach?

Answer (score 1):

This should be done automatically if you are using a Shared dataSource like shown [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/datasource/shared-datasource.html).

Comment: thanks for your reply @ Petur Subev but i already found the link, this is what i am exactly looking for ??  http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/mga6f/

Comment: It seems I do not understand you, the example shows just this. What exactly is not working fine?

Comment: actually i gone through many blogs but doesn't find solution but before your post i found the solution that link only i have commented ealier.